# Similar triangles. Where the side you are finding has two values.

Tags: geometry

$AD=10$ cm, $AE=15$ cm, $EC=3$ cm, $DB=x$, 
$ADE$ is similar to $ABC$.

The  question seemed basic however it asked for two values of $x$. I got the value $x=2$ but struggled to find another. It also mentioned to write any assumptions you have made. I know this question sounds very bad. Maybe my school made a mistake. This was in my previous mock and I can't find any questions that replicate this question. Please tell me if you think something in this question is wrong that would also help. I don't have the test paper in front of me I just did it.

[image]

Comment: two values of x is nonsensical.  In the diagram the  x is ambiguous: it isn't clear if it means the distance from the vertx to vertex/entire side, or the vertex to middle point.  It can be one or the other but not both.  The same ambiguities exist for the remaining three numbers.  10, 15, 3.  As $3 < 15$ the 3 can not refer to the entire side so I must assume the x does not refer to the entire side either.  Now we just have to determine whether the 10 and 15 refer to the entire side or partial side.

Comment: Assumption: the bases are parallel, then apply Thales' theorem (similar lengths' ratios on one side and on the other side). This will give you a **unique** value for $x$...

Comment: Also the question is unsolvable as the diagram is not to scale, x can be any value.  Nowhere on the diagram does it say the two triangles are similar or the two bases of the triangles are parallel.

Comment: Oh, you are *allowed* to make assumptions.  Well, I'll assume the lines are not parallel and x is part of the side and it equals 37.  As triangles with sides $47$ and $18$ do exist, I can not be wrong.  I advice getting a question from someone who knows how to write a proper question.  (I'm kidding; Jean Marie has the intended answer)

Comment: Constructive criticism is always appreciated. First time to post

Comment: Ah, you have editted to address my concerns.  Good. Now there is absolutely nothing wrong with the question and the answer that Jean Marie gave should be very straightforward to show that $x = 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triangle $ABC$ can be similar to $ADE$ in several different ways, according to which vertices are corresponding:

1) $A\leftrightarrow A$, $B\leftrightarrow D$, $C\leftrightarrow E$; in this case
$AB:AD=AC:AE$, which entails $x=2$;

2) $A\leftrightarrow A$, $B\leftrightarrow E$, $C\leftrightarrow D$; in this case $AB:AE=AC:AD$, which entails $x=17$;

3) $A\leftrightarrow D$, $B\leftrightarrow E$, $C\leftrightarrow A$; in this case $AB:DE=AC:AD$, which entails $x=17$ (because triangle $ADE$ is isosceles and $DE=AE$);

... and so on ...

I think you can go on filling the three remaining cases: you'll find that the only possible solutions are $x=2$ and $x=17$.